# How to combine media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have two media queries that are now doing the same thing.  How do I combine these into one query that looks for both widths?

```
@media (max-width : 480px) {...}
@media (max-width : 320px) {...}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to combine, this covers both:

```
@media (max-width : 480px) {...}
```

This applies when the width is less than 480px, and 320px is less than 480px.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if there is a listing of key widths that you should explicitly query for?  Is 480px good as a minimum?

Comment: I don't query against specific "common" viewport sizes, as they tend not to make a lot of sense in the context of most designs (plus, what happens when someone makes a new device with a non-standard resolution?).  See: http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/ and http://designshack.net/articles/css/responsive-design-why-youre-doing-it-wrong/